# Lumen 5.5 Imap package

Tags: php, imap, lumen

I am looking for a Lumen IMAP package to get emails from the client. Did a search on Google and got some packages for laravel but was unable to make them work in Lumen 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap to achieve this.

The library can be installed via composer and you are ready to use the library directly.